# Переадресация всех страниц на одну в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Испльзую код

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

все работает пока не создаю папку с таким же названием как и у ссылки

- mysite.ru/catalog/ - работает
- mysite.ru/catalog - работает

создаю папку catalog

- mysite.ru/catalog/ - работает
- mysite.ru/catalog - работает, но в строке браузера превращается в mysite.ru/catalog/?route=catalog

Под работает я подразумеваю, что переменная $_GET['route'] содержит корректные данные. Даже когда добавляет в конец /?route=catalog

Удалил все из index.php. Он теперь пустой, но проблема осталась.

Сделал чистый проект test.loc пустая папка catalog, .htaccess(смотри выше), index.php(пустой)
если ссылка без слеша он добавляет его, а не /?route=catalog
(Поправка после нескольких тестов в тестовом проекте тоже стал выдавать /?route=catalog, получается весь проект две строчки в которых нет ошибки значит дело в настройках сервера?)

Тестирую на локальной машине (Версия: Денвер-3 2012-09-16)

Подскажите пожалуйста почему и как исправить

Comment: это, видимо, не весь htaccess

Comment: Это весь htaccess . Только начал делать проект.

Comment: Видимо у вас так apache настроен. У меня редиректит все обращения на index.php, хоть существующих папок/файлов, хоть не существующих.

Comment: @Worker, я почему так подумал - если судить по htacces , у вас всё должно попадать в index.php. Возможно, проблема уже там. Что значит "работает" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне удалось понять, когда *Apache* встречает путь, который указывает на каталог, он посылает клиенту ответ с перенаправлением, причём делает это после обработки модулем *mod_rewrite*. Именно поэтому правило

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

добавит параметр к GET-запросу, а затем *Apache* выполнит перенаправление.

Избежать такого поведения можно, запретив серверу дописывать `/` в адресе, ссылающемся на каталог. Делается это при помощи директивы

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Для решения задачи файл `.htaccess` должен иметь следующий вид:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Обратите внимание на предпоследнюю строку. Она предотвращает зацикливание.